# Starting Web Api 2 with OWIN

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, owin, katana

Currently when I run my ASP.NET Web Api 2 project, it is not using any OWIN middleware.  I know this because the "Startup" class (shown below) is not being run:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyProject.Startup))]
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax's `Application_Start` is still being executed instead.

I have the following OWIN packages installed:

```
<package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
```

As far as I understand, installing the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` package should launch the application in OWIN.

I am using version 5.2.2 of the Web Api framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference I can see with my projects is that I have the *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin* package installed:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin -Version 5.2.2
```

However, there's no need to use the Global.asax file and fire up the Application_Start event. After you have configured the "Startup" class, feel free to delete it.

Comment: Ah, I had to add this AND delete the Global.asax file. Still gtting to grips with OWIN. Thanks.